# How to convert pytorch lstmcell to keras lstm or lstmcell

Tags: keras

This is example for pytorch lstmcell:

```
rnn = nn.LSTMCell(10, 20)
input = torch.randn(6, 3, 10)
hx = torch.randn(3, 20)
cx = torch.randn(3, 20)
output = []
hx, cx = rnn(input[0], (hx, cx))
output.append(hx)
```

Not sure how to convert it to keras lstm/lstmcell

Comment: What have you tried so far?
Have you looked at the keras documentation?

Comment: Yes, origial code: self.att_lstm = nn.LSTMCell(1536, 512) h_att, c_att = self.att_lstm(att_lstm_input, (state[0][0], state[1][0])) What I am tried,  inputs = Input(shape=(10, 1536))
 lstm, h_att, c_att = LSTM(units=512, input_shape=(10,1536), name='core.att_lstm', return_state=True)(inputs)  so I am not sure if it is correct

Comment: Please, *do not* post code in the comments - it is literally unreadable! Edit & update your post instead!

Answer (score 0):

Origial Pytorch code: 
self.att_lstm = nn.LSTMCell(1536, 512)
 
h_att, c_att = self.att_lstm(att_lstm_input, (state[0][0], state[1][0]))
state[0][0], state[1][0] is the tensor(10,512) 
What I am tried in keras:
`inputs = Input(shape=(10, 1536))`
`lstm, h_att, c_att = LSTM(units=512, input_shape=(10,1536), name='core.att_lstm', return_state=True)(inputs)` 
so I am not sure if it is correct.